# Reset selection of wx.lib.calendar.Calendar control?

Tags: python, calendar, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a [`wx.lib.calendar.Calendar`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.calendar.Calendar-class.html) control (not `wx.lib.calendar.CalendarCtrl`!). I am selecting a number of days using the following function call:

```
self.cal.AddSelect([days], 'green', 'white')
```

This works, and draws the days highlighted. However, I cannot work out how to reverse this (i.e., clear the selection so the days go back to their normal colouring).

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do it manually?

```
self.cal.AddSelect([days], 'black', 'white')
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I've resorted to. However, as I no longer have the original days available when I'm trying to reset I pass a list of every day in the current month. It works, but I was hoping there'd be a 'proper' way. Thanks.